# С помощью команды TASKLIST в cmd вывести список по возрастанию PID

Tags: cmd

Не могу вывести PID по росту. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: `tasklist | sort /+27`

Answer (score 0):

@Akina уже в общем-то дал ответ, единственное, что следовало бы сделать - убрать заголовок столбцов.

```
tasklist /nh | sort /+27
```